# Why is signal keyword not working in mySQL 5.1.48?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I'm using mysql v5.1.48 and red http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html. But the code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `CoreRaiseError`()
BEGIN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1001;
END$$
```

raise an

> SQL Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'SQLSTATE '45000'

From which version SIGNAL start to be a keyword?  How can I raise an exception with prior version of mysql?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/condition-handling.html) for MySQL version 5.1:

> Other statements related to conditions are `SIGNAL`, `RESIGNAL`, and `GET DIAGNOSTICS`. The `SIGNAL` and `RESIGNAL` statements are not supported until MySQL 5.5. The `GET DIAGNOSTICS` statement is not supported until MySQL 5.6.

To raise an error in older versions of MySQL, just deliberately issue an erroneous command.  I often `CALL` a non-existent procedure, for example:

```
CALL raise_error;
```

Comment: I had to alter a nice trigger I made to prevent deletion of certain kinds of records.  Tested it in 5.6 and all was cool.  Then I found out deploying to 5.1 broke so this worked for me.  What I did was: `call You_may_not_delete_those_kind_of_records`.  lol.  Ugly..but works and makes it easy to find in my logs.

Comment: Here is a question you might enjoy: [mysql 5.1 signal an error to cause PDO exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070473/mysql-5-1-signal-an-error-to-cause-pdo-exceptions).