# mysql 5.1 signal an error to cause PDO exceptions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-5.1

I know mysql 5.5 allows using `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: ...';` to raise a user defined error. And this error will stop an `INSERT` operation if it was put in the `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` on some tables. And it's also convenient for `PDO` to catch the `PDOException` and output the errorinfo() i.e. `MESSAGE_TEXT` defined in `SIGNAL SQLSTATE`. 
However, the version of mysql on the server I rent is mysql 5.1. And I want to know how can I raise a user defined error with the features like the `SIGNAL SQLSTATEMENT` in mysql 5.5.

1. interrupt a `insert` operation when it's in `before insert` trigger
2. can be caught by `PDO`

I've found some topics on similar problems, and I've tried these:

- call a nonexist procedure

  call `sp_raise_error`;
- use a function to throw an error

> https://blogs.oracle.com/svetasmirnova/entry/how_to_raise_error_in

Both can't be caught by `PDO`. So what's a solution? ( I tested on MySQL5.5 )

Comment: Can you cause an exception by simple syntax error?

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes, `PDO` will catch sql syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `SIGNAL SQLSTATE` in a lower version of MySQL (like 5.1), you will get a `1064` error. So, in order to use the function like `SIGNAL SQLSTATE` does, you can try the following steps.

### 1. Create Auxiliary Table Named "TBL_DUMMY"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TBL_DUMMY`  
(
    `error` VARCHAR(256)
);
```

### 2. Create BEFORE INSERT Trigger on TBL_DUMMY

```
delimiter $$  
CREATE TRIGGER `TRIG_BI_DUMMY` BEFORE INSERT ON `TBL_DUMMY`  
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
    SET NEW = NEW.`error`;
END $$
```

### 3. Create Procedure Named "SP_RAISE_ERROR"

```
delimiter $$  
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_RAISE_ERROR` (IN P_ERROR VARCHAR(256))  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE V_ERROR VARCHAR(300);
    SET V_ERROR := CONCAT('[ERROR: ', P_ERROR, ']');
    INSERT INTO `TBL_DUMMY` VALUES (V_ERROR);
END $$
```

### 4. Usage

Just execute `SP_RAISE_ERROR` instead of `SIGNAL SQLSTATE`. For instance, `CALL SP_RAISE_ERROR ('Password incorrect.')` will throw an exception and the message is:

```
0 15:40:23 CALL SP_RAISE_ERROR ('Password incorrect.') Error Code: 1231. Variable 'new' can't be set to the value of '[ERROR: Password incorrect.]'.
```

And you can use it in procedures:

```
IF V_ID IS NOT NULL AND V_ID <> P_ID THEN  
    CALL `SP_RAISE_ERROR` ('Title duplicated.');
END IF;
```

After that, you can extract error texts from the messages in an external program.

Comment: Tried out the above mentioned steps.But got the below mentioned error "Variable 'new' can't be set to the value of '[ERROR: Title duplicated]'
" .How it resolve?

Comment: @Rakes Yeah, that's it. You can use a regular expression to extract the part of error message. The regexp looks like `[ERROR: (.*?)]`.